# I messed up something in Index.html file of create-react-app and now my output has changed

Tags: html, reactjs, frontend, create-react-app

[here's the image, it is the last link tag to manifest.json which I changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1Mbc.jpg) so at first I was coding without changing anything in index.html file of create-react-app and it was working fine. Then I changed the **'%PUBLIC_URL%'** in    to the relative path of public folder cuz the comment below said something like that?

And now all the output of my code is messed up, the proportions of the images I inserted have changed.

I tried changing it back to %PUBLIC_URL% but the output is still like that. If anyone can help me regarding it then please do, I worked all day to get things right and now this happened T-T

Comment: That sounds like you've broken the HTML/JSX and it's now invalid, but without seeing the code there's no way we can help with that.

Comment: @DBS sorry I forgot to add the image, I have edited the question so you can see the image containing the code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.